# My Logitech G35 headphones aren't very loud on Linux (fedora 14) why?

Tags: linux, audio, fedora, headphones

I have recently purchased a set of G35 headphones.

They seem to be very loud when I use them on Windows, but when I try and use them on Fedora 14, they are very quiet and I can't seem to make them louder. I have obviously checked the sound settings in Gnome, and they are all up full.

I have got ALSA-mixer installed but seems to make no difference. There doesn't seem to be any specific drivers for these headphones for Linux.

Anyone know how to make them go a bit louder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just bought these myself and they arrived 30mins, it seems that you need to turn up one more volume control... if you run alsamixer, then select F6 to change it to the Logitech headset, youll see speak is on something pathetically low like 7, start bumping that up slowly.

Must be a Red Hat thing, I'm running RHEL6 and had same issue. Enjoy!